# Command in ffmpeg for merge image and generated video

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg in android for create video from multiple images, it has done and now i want to add more images in generated video. i found many times but not getting  any proper command in ffmpeg for that.please help

Comment: Are you using [tag:android-ffmpeg] wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command,

1.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1  -i img/%1d.jpg -vf scale=720:756 -c:v libx264 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p videos.mp4
```

If you want to add watermark image to your generated video, you can use this one:

2.

```
ffmpeg -i videos.mp4 -i watermark_img.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy watermark_videos.mp4
```

In order to create video from random images, You have to keep all images in dir called img, as you can see in first command, and just name all images in the dir, like: 1.jpg,2.jpg...N.jpg,etc , you have to name all the images in sequential number format, which is required by the ffmpeg command as you can see in the first command **-i img/%1d.jpg** , here **-start_number 1** indicates it should start from image preceding with 1 number, and go on with all the images stored in img/ dir, sequentially.

In order to understand the ffmeg command please read all of it's CLI parameters:

```
man ffmpeg
```

OR

```
ffmpeg --help
```

Comment: i think the first command will generated video from multiple images ....but i have done successfully now i want to add more images in generated video in beginning or ending.